# Apply a diff file that contains diffs from multiple files

Tags: git, diff

A co-worker sent me a diff file that contains changes to 6 different files nested in various directories. Is it possible to apply the diff recursively? I tried doing:

```
git apply file.diff
```

at the top level directory but nothing was changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try simply

```
patch -p1 < file.diff
```

Note that the argument to `-p` is the number of leading directories to strip from the patch paths. `-p1` works for git diffs (which have paths in the form `a/src/...` `b/src/...`), but you may have to adjust the argument to match your patch file.